# Is it OK to mummify a corpse?

Tags: funeral-burial-levaya, vayechi

בראשית נ ב-ג

> וַיְצַ֨ו יוֹסֵ֤ף אֶת־עֲבָדָיו֙ אֶת־הָרֹ֣פְאִ֔ים לַחֲנֹ֖ט אֶת־אָבִ֑יו
>   וַיַּחַנְט֥וּ הָרֹפְאִ֖ים אֶת־יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃ וַיִּמְלְאוּ־לוֹ֙
>   אַרְבָּעִ֣ים י֔וֹם כִּ֛י כֵּ֥ן יִמְלְא֖וּ יְמֵ֣י הַחֲנֻטִ֑ים
>   וַיִּבְכּ֥וּ אֹת֛וֹ מִצְרַ֖יִם שִׁבְעִ֥ים יֽוֹם׃

Gen 50:2-3

Then Joseph ordered the physicians in his service to embalm his father, and the physicians embalmed Israel;
It required forty days, for such is the full period of embalming. The Egyptians bewailed him seventy days;

Assuming that Joseph ordered [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gD0K7oH92U) procedure, is it OK to mummify corpse?

Comment: Is the premise of your questing based on assuming the Avos and Shvatim kept all the mitzvos so Yosef's actions can serve as a proof to allowing it?

Comment: @user6591 This is a premise that I usually challenge, but I'm also aware that there is a motivation to learn from the people before *Matan-tora*.  I wonder, in this case, was it discussed?

Comment: See Hakirah 23 http://www.hakirah.org/Vol23Landa.pdf

Comment: Israel's body was later carried (maybe 500km or more) in a very hot climate to be buried in the Holy Land.  Perhaps the body was "embalmed" simply in order to make this trip possible?

Comment: @RayButterworth Thought of it. Do somebody allow non-traditional treatment because of such conditions?

Comment: @DoubleAA Did you read that article? I can't take it seriously. The writer assumes that mummification didn't happen so he twists and imagine things to make things fit with he's perspective. (e.g process of embalm -plus, assuming the word *hanat* cannot mean mummification )

Answer (score 1):

This is something I typed up a while ago:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Commentless downvoting is not productive ,please explain the issue so maybe can be fixed or even deleted .

Comment: I would downvote an answer like this, not for the content, but for the format.  It's an image, not a text, so it can't easily be quoted from or searched, and search engines can't index it.

Comment: When I get a  chance I can change it to text ,right now I did it using my phone.

Comment: The second page is very relevant, thank you!